# Customising JAX-WS prefix of a SOAP response

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, jax-ws

### Goal

I'm implementing a web service for quite an old (but sadly unchangeable) interface. I have an issue where the client that is calling my service expects a certain namespace in the SOAP response and I'm having difficulty in changing it to match.

Considering a hello world example, I want this:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:helloResponse xmlns:ns2="http://test/">
         <return>Hello Catchwa!</return>
      </ns2:helloResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

to look like this:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <customns:helloResponse xmlns:customns="http://test/">
         <return>Hello Catchwa!</return>
      </customns:helloResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I found something similar to what I'm trying to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5719285/79450) but I'm having trouble getting similar code to execute properly. (I'd like to stick with Metro and not have to change to cxf or axis)

---

### Execution

My implementation of [`JAXBContextFactory`](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/com/sun/xml/internal/ws/developer/JAXBContextFactory.html) that returns a [`JAXBRIContext`](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/com/sun/xml/internal/bind/api/JAXBRIContext.html) looks like this:

```
import com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext;
import com.sun.xml.bind.api.TypeReference;
import com.sun.xml.ws.api.model.SEIModel;
import com.sun.xml.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class HelloJaxbContext implements JAXBContextFactory
{
  @Override
  public JAXBRIContext createJAXBContext(SEIModel seim, List<Class> classesToBind, List<TypeReference> typeReferences) throws JAXBException {
    List<Class> classList = new ArrayList<Class>();
    classList.addAll(classesToBind);

    List<TypeReference> refList = new ArrayList<TypeReference>();
    for (TypeReference tr : typeReferences) {
        refList.add(new TypeReference(new QName(tr.tagName.getNamespaceURI(), tr.tagName.getLocalPart(), "customns"), tr.type, tr.annotations));
    }
    return JAXBRIContext.newInstance(classList.toArray(new Class[classList.size()]), refList, null, seim.getTargetNamespace(), false, null);
  }  
}
```

Some test code for the web service is simply:

```
import com.sun.xml.ws.developer.UsesJAXBContext;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

@WebService(serviceName = "Hello")
@UsesJAXBContext(value = HelloJaxbContext.class)
public class Hello
{
  @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
  public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt)
  {
    return "Hello " + txt + "!";
  }
}
```

---

### Issues

In Tomcat 7.0.32 and Glassfish 3.1.2 using jaxws-rt 2.2.7 (from Maven), the above code doesn't affect my web service output (the namespace prefix is still "ns2").

Comment: Are you running this web service in Tomcat, or are you using Metro in the java distribution? They have different implementations and therefore different solutions.

Comment: I'm deploying this to Tomcat using more or less the default NetBeans configuration.

Comment: So my answer won't help you. You'll need to go through the Tomcat source to get the right information.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you started from the WSDL of the old service and generated all the various JAXB annotated request and response wrapper classes using `wsimport`, then in the generated package you should find a `package-info.java` such as

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://test/")
package com.example.test;
```

JAXB provides a mechanism for you to suggest prefix mappings on the `@XmlSchema` annotation, so you could try modifying `package-info.java` to read

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://test/",
   xmlns = { 
      @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "customns", 
         namespaceURI="http://test/")
   }
)
package com.example.test;
```

and see if that makes any difference to the generated messages.  This also has the advantage of being pure JAXB spec (i.e. not dependent on the RI-specific custom context factory).

If you need to re-run `wsimport` you can prevent it from overwriting your modified `package-info` by passing the `-npa` option to `xjc` (this tells it not to generate a `package-info.java` but instead to put all the necessary `namespace` settings on the class-level annotations instead).  Exactly how you do this depends how you're running `wsimport`.

command line:

```
wsimport -B-npa ....
```

Ant:

```
<wsimport wsdl="..." destdir="..." .... >
  <xjcarg value="-npa" />
</wsimport>
```

Maven:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>wsimport</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <xjcArgs>
          <xjcArg>-npa</xjcArg>
        </xjcArgs>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! Do you know if there's any way for my modifications to `package-info.java` being overridden when I do a clean or should I just store it separately and then copy it in after the wsimport mvn task has run?

Comment: Those who use XJC, there is a Namespace Prefix plugin.

Answer (score 4):

The recommended/standard way to achieve what you're trying to achieve is with a  [SOAPMessage Handler](http://jax-ws.java.net/articles/handlers_introduction.html). They're analogous to java web application  filters (which in theory could also work here) as they are used to implement the [Chain of Responsibility pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2004/jw-0816-chain.html). For example, in your case, you can have this :

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPBody;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;


public class SOAPBodyHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

static final String DESIRED_NS_PREFIX = "customns";
static final String DESIRED_NS_URI = "http://test/";
static final String UNWANTED_NS_PREFIX = "ns";

@Override
public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
   //do nothing
   return null;
}

@Override
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
    if ((boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY)) { //Check here that the message being intercepted is an outbound message from your service, otherwise ignore.
        try {
            SOAPEnvelope msg = context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope(); //get the SOAP Message envelope
            SOAPBody body = msg.getBody();
            body.removeNamespaceDeclaration(UNWANTED_NS_PREFIX);
            body.addNamespaceDeclaration(DESIRED_NS_PREFIX, DESIRED_NS_URI); 
        } catch (SOAPException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SOAPBodyHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    return true; //indicates to the context to proceed with (normal)message processing
}

@Override
public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
      //do nothing
   return null;
}

@Override
public void close(MessageContext context) {
      //do nothing

}
```

}

On your Service Implementation Bean class declaration, add

```
  @HandlerChain(file = "handler-chain.xml")
```

The annotation above is a reference to the configuration file that actually allows your handler to kick-in. The config file will look something like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
     <javaee:handler-chains xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <javaee:handler-chain>
           <javaee:handler>
              <javaee:handler-class>your.handler.FQN.here</javaee:handler-class>
           </javaee:handler>
        </javaee:handler-chain>
     </javaee:handler-chains>
```

Try this at home. This specific code has NOT been tested

Comment: I've tried your code but it changes the namespace and prefix of the Body element of the SOAP response, not the content that is generated by JAX-WS. i.e. your code adds a namespace declaration to the Body element but doesn't change the namespace declaration of the helloResponse element. Thanks for trying!

Comment: I have successfully used a message handler to customize namespace prefixes, a detailed outline is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43316912/149895

Answer (score 0):

In the reference implementation, I did this to finally make it work. See [schemaLocation ignored when marshalling JAXB Classes using Metro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778748/schemalocation-ignored-when-marshalling-jaxb-classes-using-metro)