# Modify SOAP envelop to include Namespace

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, cxf, jax-ws

I have SOAP response of something like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <calculate_response>
            <tid>33433</tid>
            <status>0</status>
            <reason>0</reason>
        </calculate_response>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to add namespace to it and it should look something like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    xmlns:def="http://com.sample.xyz/Messages">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <def:calculate_response>
            <tid>33433</tid>
            <status>0</status>
            <reason>0</reason>
        </def:calculate_response>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have created stub using `wsimport`, and I need this response to be modified before processing it further.

Actually it's a two step process as I understood , first step is to add namespace to soap envelop then add prefix to it.
Regarding prefix part I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889943/customising-jax-ws-prefix-of-a-soap-response) . I'm not clear about how to do first step.

Note: I need to modify response at client side and I cannot change SOAP at server side.

Comment: Why do you need to change the response at client side? What are you trying to achieve by adding that namespace?

Comment: Actually soap client is expecting a response to be of type `{http://com.sample.xyz/Messages}calculate_response`, where as it is not returned by the server, It happens to be missing namespace.

Comment: Why don't you regenerate the Soap client classes so that they match the response sent by the server?

Comment: I did, I used wsdl, xsd from server to generate client classes but it is expecting a response to be like that where as server is not returning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved this with the help of `SOAP Message Handlers`

I've written `handler` which implements `SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>`
and `overridden` its `handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context){}` with following implementation.

```
//Get soapElement from your soap request.
if (soapElement.getTagName().equalsIgnoreCase("calculate_response")) {
       soapElement.setElementQName(
         new QName("http://com.sample.xyz/Messages",
                  "calculate_response",
                  "def"));
```